# Override Order PDF Abstract Model From Custom Module

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order, model, pdf, override-model

I want to override magento function model which located at **app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Abstract.php** `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Abstract`, how to override the insertOrder function at this model from custom module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magento does not allow you to rewrite abstract classes.

The simplest solution would be copying the file to **app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Abstract.php** and then editing the function as needed.

The only other solution would be rewriting all the classes that extend the abstract class within your own custom module. To do so, you would need rewrite all 4 classes that extend it as follows.

**app/etc/modules/Custom_Module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config>
    <modules>
        <Custom_Module>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Sales />
            </depends>
        </Custom_Module>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/Custom/Module/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config>
    <modules>
        <Custom_Module>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Custom_Module>
    </modules>

    <global>
        <models>
            <custom_module>
                <class>Custom_Module_Model</class>
            </custom_module>

            <sales>
                <rewrite>
                    <order_pdf_creditmemo>Custom_Module_Model_Order_Pdf_Creditmemo</order_pdf_creditmemo>
                    <order_pdf_invoice>Custom_Module_Model_Order_Pdf_Invoice</order_pdf_invoice>
                    <order_pdf_shipment>Custom_Module_Model_Order_Pdf_Shipment</order_pdf_shipment>
                    <order_pdf_shipment_packaging>Custom_Module_Model_Order_Pdf_Shipment_Packaging</order_pdf_shipment_packaging>
                </rewrite>
            </sales>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/Custom/Module/Model/Order/Pdf/Creditmemo.php**

```
<?php
class Custom_Module_Model_Order_Pdf_Creditmemo extends Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Creditmemo {
    protected function insertOrder(&$page, $obj, $putOrderId = true) {
        parent::insertOrder($page, $obj, $putOrderId = true);

        /* Add your custom code here */
    }
}
```

**app/code/local/Custom/Module/Model/Order/Pdf/Invoice.php**

```
<?php
class Custom_Module_Model_Order_Pdf_Invoice extends Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Invoice {
    protected function insertOrder(&$page, $obj, $putOrderId = true) {
        parent::insertOrder($page, $obj, $putOrderId = true);

        /* Add your custom code here */
    }
}
```

**app/code/local/Custom/Module/Model/Order/Pdf/Shipment.php**

```
<?php
class Custom_Module_Model_Order_Pdf_Shipment extends Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Shipment {
    protected function insertOrder(&$page, $obj, $putOrderId = true) {
        parent::insertOrder($page, $obj, $putOrderId = true);

        /* Add your custom code here */
    }
}
```

**app/code/local/Custom/Module/Model/Order/Pdf/Shipment/Packaging.php**

```
<?php
class Custom_Module_Model_Order_Pdf_Shipment_Packaging extends Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Shipment_Packaging {
    protected function insertOrder(&$page, $obj, $putOrderId = true) {
        parent::insertOrder($page, $obj, $putOrderId = true);

        /* Add your custom code here */
    }
}
```